# belongs_to relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, rails-activerecord

I have following active record class

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

in the code when I try this

```
Car.first.owner
```

it gives me error "undefined method owner"

Can any one plz let me now if I'm missing any thing

Comment: Is there a class `Owner`?

Comment: yes its also a active record, but it does not have has_many relation with car.

Comment: would it be something like "undefined method `owner' for nil:NilClass"? In this case your table is empty, so no 'first' element to get an owner from...

Comment: Its not empty, I check. cars table has a valid owner_id

Comment: Did you declare the corresponding `has_many` part of the relationship? Rebooting rails server/console can help too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write the relation on the Owner side : `has_one :car` or `has_many :cars` depending on your needs.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :car
end
```